# Duplicate error in transactions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, transactions

I have a transaction that updates the table *produces*. It sets a *product* to be manufactured by a certain *machine*. However if this *machine* already exists in the table I get

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'produces_PK'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.TblProduces'.

How do I solve this problem?

This is the transaction:

```
create proc update_products_and_machine_proc @machinNum int, @productName varchar(10) as
begin tran update_products_and_machine
    update TblProduces set machineNumber=@machinNum
    from TblProduces inner join TblMachine on TblMachine.machineNumber=
    TblProduces.machineNumber inner join TblProduct on TblProduces.productNumber=
    TblProduct.productNumber
    where TblProduct.productName=@productName and exists (select TblMachine.machineNumber
    from TblMachine where TblMachine.isWorking='true')
if @@ERROR <> 0 begin
    rollback tran
    goto on_error
end
commit tran update_products_and_machine
on_error: Print 'ERROR';
```

Comment: What is the primary key of TblProduces? Your `exists` subquery just checks if there's any working machine, is that correct?

Comment: Produces is a connecting table between "Product" and "Machine", so productnumber and machinenumber are the primary keys and are the only fields in "produces" table. Also, you are correct

Comment: Is this query trying to update all the machineNumbers for a given Product to the same machineNum in the TblProduces table?  This would cause the primary key error.  You either need to limit the update to one cross reference record or delete the extraneous records first.

Answer (score 2):

Check if MachineNumber exists before attempting to update.  You can use `EXISTS` or `COUNT`

For instance:

```
DECLARE @Exists INT

SELECT @Exists = COUNT(MachineNumber)
FROM TblProduces
WHERE MachineNumber = @machinNum

IF @Exists = 0
BEGIN
     -- Perform UPDATE
END
```

Comment: This solution is not helping me since I want to update the records even if the machine exists

Comment: @user2023203 - you have a constraint that is stopping multiple machines with the same id from being inserted into the table.  My answer will help you maintain this integrity without violating the constraint. If you wish to UPDATE an existing machine you can adjust the query to `UPDATE tblProduces SET column = Value WHERE MachineNumber = @machinNum'